# Send a message from one PC to another using RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I have three PCs, where two PCs are producers and one is the consumer. Using Python, how do I get them to communicate with each other. I am able to do the same on localhost, I followed the tutorials on the RabbitMQ website. There they mentioned that all I have to do is add the IP Address instead of localhost, but that doesn't work. Please help out here.

**Edit:**

I have made the following changes to my code to validate the username and password using pika. Still I am getting errors

**The code for receive.py is as follows:**

```
import pika

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('sneha', 'sneha')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbit@sneha-System-Product-Name', 5672, '/', credentials))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='hello',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

**I get the following errors:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receive.py", line 4, in <module>
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbit@sneha-System-Product-Name', 5672, '/', credentials))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
    self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
    self._open_error_result.is_ready)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Comment: add the code you are running. Also mention any error if you see on the terminal

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Answer (score 0):

Tutorials use the `guest` RabbitMQ user account which is automatically created on a fresh install and have all permissions. However, [this account is restricted to connections from `localhost` only](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#loopback-users) on purpose: because of its unlimited permissions, it would be a security concern for a default install. This account is good for playing with RabbitMQ but not for a production use.

Therefore, with RabbitMQ on a remote computer, it refuses the connection with the `guest` account and you get the `ProbableAuthenticationError` error.

Now, you have two solutions:

1. The recommended one is to create another user, give it the appropriate permissions and use it for your applications. This is described in the [Access Control documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html).
2. Disable the "only from localhost" protection on the `guest` account. To do that, you need to use the following RabbitMQ configuration:

   ```
   [
     {rabbit, [
         {loopback_users, []}
       ]}
   ].
   ```

   Please read the [documentation of `loopback_users`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) (you will have to search for `loopback_users` in this page).

Comment: hi, after creating users, will there be any change in the code as such? or will the code remain same as what i have mentioned above?

Comment: You will need to change it to specify the user name and password. I don't know Pika, so refer to the documentation of Pika to learn how to do this.